# Why isn't my Samba machine browseable on the network?

Tags: networking, samba

I have a Samba machine - set up as a standalone server, and it's not showing when browsing the network. The workgroup is OFFICE (yah, I know.... generic... but it was before my time).

One can get to the machine via its IP address, but *not* via browsing the Microsoft Network... Macs, Linux, Windows - none can see the server in browsing.

Any idea what may be wrong? Server works fine by IP.

Comment: Well, depending on the versions you are running, there is a `browseable` option to be used on Samba, as you can see here: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#BROWSEABLE

Comment: Browsable is only for shares, not servers. But browse list seems interesting

Answer (score 0):

The Samba server must be defined in the DNS server you're using to make it *searchable* (not "browsable": that is a samba setting) by name.  Edit the relevant DNS server settings to make this happen.

As your question does not mention any network settings, (rather vague) the answer doesn't contain the exact commands neither (rather vague too).  Alternatively, if all of your clients are Windows/Mac machines, `winbind` on the samba server can be used as well. (again: rather vageu)

So update your question if this answer is too vague with your DNS settings, number of clients / printers /... and I'll update my answer to become more exact as well.

(an Infrastructure diagram would be best.  Something like [this](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ReKyN2dvjmM/VNNS83EA9II/AAAAAAAAG1g/LoWc4uXTWBs/w807-h571-no/Infra%2Bdiagram.gif))